# Avoid redirrect or endless loop while auto-submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want my form to take action without clicking on a submit button. I achieved that but now I'm at a crossroad. If I use a script URL in the action attribute my user gets jumped to another page. If I target the script itself I get him in an endless loop. How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
<form class="myForm" action="includes/teste.php" method="POST" id="form-id">
  <input name="myField" type="hidden" id="myField" class="myField" value="" />
</form>

<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
  function showPosition(pos){
    document.getElementById('myField').value = (pos.coords.latitude+","+pos.coords.longitude);
    document.getElementById("form-id").submit()  
  }
</script>
```

In case you're wondering this is what teste.php should be doing:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["origin"] = $_POST['myField'];
?>
```

Basically that's what I want to achieve but without endlessly reloading the page or redirrecting the user.

The JS code itself sends the longitude and the latitude of the user's current location to the value of the hidden input. I need to fetch it from there and store it in a $_SESSION.

Comment: Instead of submitting an actual form, send the data to the server in the background using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create the $_SESSION variable in PHP you can create a cookie with JS and then access it with PHP wherever you need using $_COOKIE['name'].

Just to make it easier, add this to the head of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value, lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )

var domain_string = valid_domain ? ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
"; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * lifespan_in_days +
"; path=/" + domain_string ;
} 
</script>
```

And then replace `document.getElementById("form-id").submit()` with `set_cookie( "origin", pos.coords.latitude+","+pos.coords.longitude, 7 );`